# ListItem Value not updating on ItemUpdated, only after hitting Refresh

Tags: sharepoint, listitem, event-receiver

I am new to Sharepoint.
I have an EventReceiver hooked to an ItemUpdated event and I want to write a text in a field. 
When I upload a file the event triggers ok, it goes through the code on debugging, seems to update but my property does not receive the text it's supposed to. However after I hit refresh on the page, I can see the updated value.

Here's my code

```
    public override void ItemUpdated(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
        base.ItemUpdated(properties);

        string folderPath = string.Empty;
        SPListItem item = properties.ListItem;
        if (item.File.ParentFolder != null)
        {
            folderPath = item.File.ParentFolder.ServerRelativeUrl;
        }

        AssignPropertyToField("Folder Name", item, folderPath);
    }        

    private void AssignPropertyToField(string fieldName, SPListItem item, string folderPath)
    {
        item[fieldName] = folderPath;

        this.EventFiringEnabled = false;
        item.SystemUpdate();
        this.EventFiringEnabled = true;
    }
```

Thank you in advance for suggestions,

Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If possible, try [ItemUpdating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spitemeventreceiver.itemupdating.aspx) instead of [ItemUpdated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spitemeventreceiver.itemupdated.aspx).

Since ItemUpdated is asynchronous, you should not count on it being called before the page is refreshed. With ItemUpdating, note that the list item has not yet been saved so you do not need to call [SystemUpdate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms461526.aspx).

```
public override void ItemUpdating(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
    string folderPath = string.Empty;
    SPListItem item = properties.ListItem;
    if (item.File.ParentFolder != null)
    {
        folderPath = item.File.ParentFolder.ServerRelativeUrl;
    }
    properties.AfterProperties["FolderNameInternalName"] = folderPath;
}
```

In your case, the question is going to be whether you will be able to retrieve the updated parent folder information within the ItemUpdating event. My sample code above will take the previously existing folder information. This code will give you the wrong URL if the file is being moved to a different folder.

Comment: thank you, what you are saying makes sense. i have 2 questions however. 1) I am not at work now so I can't test, but I have tried ItemUpdating and received a <nativestack> exception with code 0x81020015. Probably because on that event, the properties.ListItem object is Null? 2) you mention that I don't need to call SystemUpdate() at all, should I also avoid calling Update() ? Thanks,

Comment: For #1, I'm not sure what's causing the error, but properties.ListItem should not be null. It would be null for ItemAdding, but not for ItemUpdating. For #2, that is correct. You don't need to call Update, because the list item is already updating. The ItemUpdating event let's you slip any last minute changes (or cancel the changes altogether) before the Update actually saves.

Comment: i am trying to apply your solution, however: on the event ItemUpdating, the properties.AferProperties collection has a count of 0. Is there any specific reason for this, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: properties.AfterProperties.ChangedProperties.Count will be 0 until you change a property. SPItemEventDataCollection has an internal property named Properties that maintains the values from the list. While you cannot get a count from it, you can get the individual values through the [Item](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spitemeventdatacollection.item) property.

Answer (score 1):

You can call item.Update() instead of item.SystemUpdate()

Note that this way the ItemUpdated event handler will be called twice, so you need to make sure to only do the update if item[fieldName] is different from folderPath in AssignPropertyToField, to avoid infinite loop.

Comment: thank you that is useful info but still does not answer my question. thank you nonetheless. i tried with Update instead of UpdateSystem but nothing changed. Field remains empty and updates only after a page refresh

Answer (score 0):

What you can do, is to define in the elements.xml in the definition of the ItemUpdated  receiver that it should be run synchronous. See this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff512765.aspx